# Python- SQL update operation; no errors but doesn't actually update my database

Tags: python, sql, sql-update

Im using python and SQL to make a database for customer accounts. I am trying to give the option to update a customer's details. I have done what I believe would update the table but when I print the contents nothing has changed. Please can you tell me where I am going wrong?

```
def update_Customer(self):
    # create sqlite connection            
    conn = sqlite3.connect("lanyard.db", timeout=5)
    c = conn.cursor()
    # if texfield is empty
    if self.TextField1.get() !="":
        if self.TextField2.get() != "":
            nameChange1 = self.TextField2.get()
            CusNo = self.TextField1.get()
            c.execute("""
                UPDATE customer
                SET first_name = 'nameChange1'
                WHERE customer_id = 'CusNo'""")
            conn.commit()
        if self.TextField3.get() != "":
            nameChange2 = self.TextField3.get()
            CusNo = self.TextField1.get()
            c.execute("""
                UPDATE CUSTOMER
                SET second_name = 'nameChange2'
                WHERE customer_id = 'CusNo'""")
            conn.commit()
        if self.TextField4.get() == "":
            nameChange3 = self.TextField4.get()
            CusNo = self.TextField1.get()
            c.execute("""
                UPDATE CUSTOMER
                SET address = 'nameChange3'
                WHERE customer_id = 'CusNo'""")
            conn.commit()
    conn.commit()
    c.close()

    # clear input
    self.TextField1.delete(0, END)
    self.TextField2.delete(0, END)
    self.TextField3.delete(0, END)
    self.TextField4.delete(0, END)
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot [parameters](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html):

```
        nameChange1 = self.TextField2.get()
        CusNo = self.TextField1.get()
        c.execute("""
            UPDATE customer
            SET first_name = ?
            WHERE customer_id = ?""", (nameChange1, CusNo,) )
```

Comment: nameChange1 should be a parameter too.

Comment: I had already tried adding those parameters in but got an error, tried again as you did it and got the same error. Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1399, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "J:\University\U08007\D\SQL_Lanyard_GUI1.py", line 343, in update_Customer
    WHERE customer_id = 'CusNo'""", (nameChange1, CusNo,))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 2 supplied.

Answer (score 0):

The code is not complete. The class, I am assuming has CREATE TABLE function.
Additionally, look at return value of

```
c.execute
```